# Django-activity-stream : Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I try to use the Django-activity-stream package but I have a problem with the configuration (http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html).

The name of my project is **proj** and I want use this package on the **main_app** activity.

/proj

/proj          /main_app

So in main_app/apps.py I did this :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from actstream import registry


class MainAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main_app'

    def ready(self):
        registry.register(self.get_model('Car'))
```

But I have a error when I add this line in main_app/**init**.py :

```
default_app_config = 'main_app.apps.MainAppConfig'
```

The error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
   self.check_apps_ready()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready

 raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
 django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My settings :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'main_app',
    'actstream',
]
```

Edit (2) :

Now I have this in main_app/apps.py :

from django.apps import AppConfig

```
class MainAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main_app'

def ready(self):
    from actstream import registry
    registry.register(self.get_model('Car'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is not ready yet when you run against it. You should set the environment variable, and setup django (which usually runs when wsgi loads the django application):

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
django.setup()

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MainAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main_app'

    def ready(self):
        from actstream import registry
        registry.register(self.get_model('Car'))
```

Comment: Where did you write this ?

Comment: I write this in apps.py of my application (see my post, I edited) but I have the same error :/

Comment: Thank you, but now nothing happens when I do "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: When I locate `from actstream import registry` in `def ready(self)`, it's works.. why ?

Comment: what do you mean by "locate"

Comment: Because it runs actstream later, with the instance, and not when the class is declared. Maybe it's by design

Comment: So should I keep the same code ? Because in the notice, it's different

Comment: héhé, it's crazy.. I find nobody using this. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MainAppConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'main_app'

```
def ready(self):
    from actstream import registry
    registry.register(self.get_model('Car'))
```

Why? Because registry is not imported until ready() is called. If registry is imported beforehand, we see in stack trace that actstream.compat imports fields from django.contrib.contentypes. This module imports the model ContentType. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded . "In other words, your applications’ root packages and the modules that define your application configuration classes shouldn’t import any models, even indirectly."

To completely fix this issue, we have to somehow prevent any other models imported indirectly before we can use actstream's registry module.